# Kadesh while catching up

Tags: tefilla, kaddish

Many times while davening I will fall slightly behind and kadesh will start while I am still in middle of a paragraph. Should I answer or continue davening (or just answer and continue davening, pausing to answer amen each time). Does it depend on what one is davening?